# End execution of namespaces after namespace with if statement finishes in csharp

Tags: c#

I am trying to build a simple program that will perform checks within namespaces and move to another part of the code with also namespaces included.

```
namespace A
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            if (condition) {
            return; // stop execution of the namespace B
           {
        }
    }
}


namespace B
{
    public class Something
    {
        public static void run()
        {
         do something;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Edited namespace B, to exclude void Main() as per suggestion. That is actual structure of the code I am trying to run.

I am expecting to evaluate the if statement in namespace A and make a decision whether to proceed to namespace B. I have tried including part of the code from namespace B in A, and that works, but I need to have an option to expand my checks and would like to make it neatly organized.

Can anyone help?

---

Clearer example: my first program B.cs is as described below:

```
namespace B
{
    public class Something
    {
        public static void run()
        {
         do something;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### I needed to add another functionality (I have separate A.cs, D.cs, C.cs) to this program that will perform checks whether or not to run this program. I am trying to see what is the best way to combine the code.

Comment: I'm not sure I get your question right, but can't you just call `B.Program.Main()` from within A.Program.Main? (by the way, having multiple main methods is usually considered bad practice)

Comment: Don´t jump back and forward arbitrarily in your program. It seems you´re looking for some old-school `goto`, which is considered bad practice since **ages**, as it´s incredible hard to follow your program-flow. Instead you should structure your program into logical chunks of actions that belong together - in classes.

Comment: Question aside, I would consider this to be bad practice as it wouldn't be clear to someone looking in the code from namespace B that execution may stop.

Comment: @TilmanB.akaNerdyyy thanks alot for your suggestion I have amended my code.

Comment: terminology note: namespaces don't get executed, methods get executed. namespaces are just a way to organise your code, they're not a runnable item

Comment: @HimBromBeere could you possibly give me an example of how to arrange this code in classes?

Comment: you've already split it into two classes (and also into two namespaces). It's unclear what the issue is exactly. Can you give a clearer, perhaps more detailed example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I would _guess_ you mean to do something like `if (condition) {
              Something.run();
           }` (and you would need `using B;` at the top of your first file, so it references the other namespace and understands where the class `Something` comes from). But your description doesn't really make it obvious if that's what you're talking about or not.

Comment: P.S. I note you made `run()` static, but you should be careful about the difference between static and instance methods/variables, and choose the most appropriate kind in each case. I think maybe you need to study [object-oriented programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/object-oriented-programming) in general and get a better idea what the concepts are, what you can do and what it all means, then you've got some chance of designing a coherent logical application. P.S. don't over-use namespaces if you don't actually need them

Comment: @ADyson that might be it, I will try it. I will also go through references you provided to learn more. I am new to C#. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. "Best" is a subjective term and its definition will be entirely different in different circumstances. We, as yet, know almost nothing about your exact circumstances, so we can't advise on the "best" way. Even if we did, we'd probably still have different ideas about what is really "best"! Also it's still unclear precisely what logic you want to implement, or what difficulty you've faced in doing so, so I'm not convinced we can give specific advice on _any_ way. Maybe some `if` statements? That's about the only thing I can say, given the lack of detail provided.